# Copying plot from another device to RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to change my work flow for simultaneously displaying and saving my plots in R.

Until now, following advice given on two other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621012/display-and-save-the-plot-simultaneously-in-r-rstudio/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058606/saving-plot-as-pdf-and-simultaneously-display-it-in-the-window-x11/)), I've done the following:

1. Clear all devices: `graphics.off(); dev.new()`
2. Create a device instance for my desired file type (`pdf` is most common): `pdf("file.pdf")`.
3. Return to the RStudio device: `dev.set(which = dev.list()["RStudioGD"])`
4. Plotting functions. `plot(1:10, 1:10)` etc.
5. Copy to device: `dev.copy(which = dev.list()["pdf"])`
6. Close device: `dev.off(which = dev.list()["pdf"])`

This has worked great for some time, but I've noticed an issue: sometimes the settings of my plot window in RStudio are all screwed up and this in turn gets passed on to my my file. Specifically, I'm always shrinking / stretching the plot window portion of my RStudio work space to make my code / console more or less dominant (e.g., to the point where `par("pin")` returns (11.27, .157) ).

To get around this, I've tried switching the order of operations to write first to the device and then copy this to RStudio (i.e., to switch steps 3 & 4, then copy to `RStudioGD` instead of the external device).

However, while the file is written as expected, nothing shows up in RStudio, and there are no warnings produced:

```
graphics.off(); dev.new()
pdf("womp.pdf")
plot(1:10, 1:10)

dev.copy(which = dev.list()["RStudioGD"]) #apparently does nothing!!
invisible(dev.off(which = dev.list()["pdf"]))
```

Is it impossible to copy something from a device to RStudio?

Comment: Any reason for not using 'ggplot' and 'ggsave'? You can specify the saved image size easily, and ggplot plays nicely with rstudio.

Comment: Many years later, I'll report that I don't do the simultaneous plotting thing anymore. I use RStudioGD for development work, or use a device from the start for plots I plan to keep on disk

Comment: what's the thinking there? Any chance you could post an example as an answer? This is intriguing!