# Why does dev.new() open RStudioGD- and png device?

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I need to understand how "device works" and followed the [great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23633735/5784831) and expected `dev.new()` just creates a new default device. But this does not happen:

```
getOption("device")
# [1] "RStudioGD"
dev.list()
# NULL
dev.cur()
# null device 
# 1 
dev.new()
# NULL
dev.list()
# RStudioGD       png ?? why also png ??
# 2         3 
dev.cur()
# RStudioGD 
# 2
```

Is that behavior on purpose? I guess not - why should it just choose png?
(I tried around with devices and `png()` before, but cannot find that default parameters changed.

---

After the first answer I also tried `dev.new()` with RGui (Windows, x64). Still another behavior:

```
> dev.new()
# opens a graphics window
> dev.list()
# windows 
#   2 
> getOption("device") # Just the function?
function (width, height, pointsize, record, rescale, xpinch, 
    ypinch, bg, canvas, gamma, xpos, ypos, buffered, title, restoreConsole, 
    clickToConfirm, fillOddEven, family = "", antialias) 
{
    check <- Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_", "")
    msg <- "screen devices should not be used in examples etc"
    if (identical(check, "stop")) 
        stop(msg, domain = NA)
    else if (identical(check, "warn")) 
        warning(msg, immediate. = TRUE, noBreaks. = TRUE, domain = NA)
    new <- list()
    if (!missing(width)) 
        new$width <- as.double(width)
    if (!missing(height)) 
        new$height <- as.double(height)
    if (!missing(pointsize)) 
        new$pointsize <- as.double(pointsize)
    if (!missing(record)) 
        new$record <- record
    if (!missing(rescale)) 
        new$rescale <- rescale
    if (!missing(xpinch)) 
        new$xpinch <- as.double(xpinch)
    if (!missing(ypinch)) 
        new$ypinch <- as.double(ypinch)
    if (!missing(bg)) 
        new$bg <- bg
    if (!missing(canvas)) 
        new$canvas <- canvas
    if (!missing(gamma)) 
        new$gamma <- gamma
    if (!missing(xpos)) 
        new$xpos <- as.integer(xpos)
    if (!missing(ypos)) 
        new$ypos <- as.integer(ypos)
    if (!missing(buffered)) 
        new$buffered <- buffered
    if (!missing(title)) 
        new$title <- title
    if (!missing(restoreConsole)) 
        new$restoreConsole <- restoreConsole
    if (!missing(clickToConfirm)) 
        new$clickToConfirm <- clickToConfirm
    if (!missing(fillOddEven)) 
        new$fillOddEven <- fillOddEven
    if (!missing(antialias)) 
        new$antialias <- match.arg(antialias, aa.win)
    d <- check.options(new = new, envir = .WindowsEnv, name.opt = ".Windows.Options", 
        reset = FALSE, assign.opt = FALSE)
    rescale <- match(d$rescale, c("R", "fit", "fixed"))
    if (is.na(rescale)) 
        stop("invalid value for 'rescale'")
    antialias <- pmatch(d$antialias, aa.win)
    invisible(.External(C_devga, "", d$width, d$height, 
        d$pointsize, d$record, rescale, d$xpinch, d$ypinch, d$canvas, 
        d$gamma, d$xpos, d$ypos, d$buffered, .PSenv, d$bg, d$restoreConsole, 
        d$title, d$clickToConfirm, d$fillOddEven, family, antialias))
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000015978308>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
```

Comment: Is the example reproducible? I thought it might only happen on my PC...

Comment: I have the same output.

Comment: Exactly the same output for me also. Don't know why. One answer to your question would be very welcome

Comment: @lovalery which output does he want to see?

Comment: @manro, I don't want anything ;-) I just would like to understand like Christoph how exactly dev.new() works and why this choice by default regarding .png

Comment: @lovalery i puzzled out.  Soon i make an answer.

Comment: @lovalery I do it.

Comment: Thanks for the overview @manro but I'm afraid it doesn't answer Christoph's question about understanding the default behavior of `dev.new()` and possibly how to change it.

Comment: @lovalery ah, ok. Maybe there: https://community.rstudio.com he can recieve more information from devs of this app.

Comment: @lovalery See my edit to the question.

Comment: @Christoph, thanks for the edit.  I also run through RGui and got the same output as you. And like you, I still don't understand how to set the default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An introduction to `dev.***`

By default in `Windows` we have two graphic devices after `dev.new`

```
dev.list()
NULL
dev.cur()
null device 
          1 
dev.new()
NULL
dev.list()
RStudioGD       png 
        2         3
```

**Which graphic devices can we also add:**

*a) pop-out window (`"quartz"` on MacOS, `"X11"` on Linux. );*

```
windows()
dev.list()
RStudioGD       png   windows 
        2         3         4
```

*b) pdf;*

```
pdf()
dev.list()
RStudioGD       png       pdf 
        2         3         4
```

*c) png, svg, tiff, jpeg.*

```
png()
svg()
tiff()
jpeg()
dev.list()
RStudioGD       png       pdf       png       svg      tiff      jpeg 
        2         3         4         5         6         7         8
```

To make a graphic output:

```
dev.set(5)
png 
  5 
  ggplot(data = mpg) + 
      geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))
dev.off()
```

After this a file with our plot is generated, but a "png" graphic output is gone away from our `dev.list`

```
dev.list()
pdf  svg tiff 
  4    6    7
```

We can move between graphic devices with `dev.next() and dev.prev()`

To close all graphic devices we use `graphics.off()`

```
graphics.off()
dev.list()
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your summary - really unexpected. Two points:
Do you understand WHY two graphic devices are opened? Is the reason documented anywhere? Is it the same on Linux? I just had a look at the `?dev.new()` again and it states  `dev.new opens a new device.` which sounds like "one" device...

Comment: Second, I would add the comments from the answer linked in my question to your question:

"dev.close() => IMPORTANT: AT THIS POINT the plot is saved as
png("x.png") in the current working directory.
Three actions takes place at this point, all at once:
1. closes device 4
2. save the plot as "x.png"
3. sets the dev.next() (which is RStudioGD) as the current device"
To me, this was also really unexpected and you need to know it when you want to understand when something actually gets saved...

Comment: Should `getOption("device")` not output `RStudioGD` and `png` as used?

Comment: @Christoph I can't say anything about RStudio on Linux. I don't know what else to say to you about this behavior.  Maybe you want to use ```ggsave```  from ```ggplot2``` or just save by ```export``` button, if don't believe to ```dev.***``` things? Or avoid the ```RStudioGD``` output.