# R ggplot2: annotation_custom of raster grob does not plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

***UPDATE***
*Turns out it was an issue of not being able to produce raster graphics over a remote desktop connection.*

I want to insert an image from file into a plot made with ggplot2.  This question has already been asked here ([Inserting an image to ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917049/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot2)) but for me the accepted answer produces a plot devoid of any image.  There are no errors or warnings: the axes, grid, and points all plot just fine but there's no R logo ([exported plot](http://postimg.org/image/rik65wnd7/); I couldn't upload an image here).  Code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(png)
library(grid)

img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)

qplot(1:10, 1:10, geom="blank") +
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  geom_point()
```

I've tried playing around with the xy values and have used several different images and formats but to no avail.

The problem I'm having is specific to using a rastergrob object with annotate_custom(), as the examples given on the [ggplot2 documentation site for annotate_custom()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/annotation_custom.html) work just fine, e.g.:

```
library(gridExtra)

qplot(1:10, 1:10, geom = "blank") + 
  annotation_custom(grob = tableGrob(head(iris[ ,1:3])),
  xmin = 3, xmax = 6, ymin = 2, ymax = 8)
```

I'm using 64-bit R version 3.0.2 on windows with ggplot2 version 0.9.3.1 and my packages are all updated.

Any thoughts would be most welcome, and apologies if I'm missing something simple!

Comment: I got a plot with nice R logo. Are all your packages updated?

Comment: Curious...I was worried it was something particular me.  My packages are all updated, I'll add that to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in an answer to this question ([R base package grid does not produce output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728190/r-base-package-grid-does-not-produce-output/10769839#10769839)), "R does not produce raster images correctly in the window device over Remote Desktop Connection. If a raster image is required, the plot must be output to another device."

I was accessing R using a Remote Desktop Connection and thus the raster grob would not plot.