# R ggplot background image not showing

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Problem

I want to draw a number of arrows on a map. With some googling, I've learned that `annotation_custom` with `rasterGrob` can do the thing:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(png)
library(grid)

img = readPNG('floorplan.png')
g = rasterGrob(img, interpolate = TRUE)

data = read.csv('est_err_structured.csv', header = FALSE)
x1 = data$V1
y1 = data$V2
x2 = data$V3
y2 = data$V4

p = ggplot() +
geom_segment(data = data, mapping = aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2),
            arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, 'cm'))) +
annotation_custom(g, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
xlab('x (m)') +
ylab('y (m)') +
theme_bw()

pdf('err_on_map.pdf')
p
dev.off()
```

However, when I run this script, I only got arrows but not background image:

[image]

### Attachment

- [`est_err_structured.csv`](https://gist.github.com/gsongsong/2e86922e2e80006779dd7706c072e015)
- `floorplan.png`
  [image]

### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16418186
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769839

Comment: Just curious, is this a gps tracker data for your cat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to study ggplot2 a bit more. E.g., the variables mapped within `aes` are taken from the data.frame defined as `data` and in this example you must pass it to `ggplot`. I think `annotation_custom` somehow needs it to get the proper coordinates or dimensions.

```
p = ggplot(data) +
  annotation_custom(g, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = V1, y = V2, xend = V3, yend = V4),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, 'cm'))) +
  xlab('x (m)') +
  ylab('y (m)') +
  theme_bw()
```

You'll need to pass the plot `width` and `height` to `pdf` in order to align the image correctly with the plot.

[image: resulting plot]

**Edit:**

@baptiste recommends `annotation_raster`, which makes the positioning easier:

```
ggplot(data) +
  annotation_raster(img, xmin = 50, xmax = 600, ymin = 20, ymax = 400) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = V1, y = V2, xend = V3, yend = V4),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, 'cm'))) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 600), ylim = c(20, 400)) +
  xlab('x (m)') +
  ylab('y (m)') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: resulting plot 2]

Comment: one could argue that it's a bug, since any data.frame, e.g. `ggplot(iris)`, will do.

Comment: @baptiste I vaguely remember you saying that `annotation_custom` is a horrible hack. :)

Comment: a buggy/unfinished function, yes. But quite useful nonetheless (what I consider a horrible hack is when it's combined with clip=off to place things outside the panel). Anyway, here annotation_raster might work too.

Comment: @baptiste Yes, but it seems to have the same "bug".